# How do I deploy .NET Framework 4 using Active Directory deployment?

Tags: deployment, active-directory

I know it's possible to deploy earlier versions of the .NET framework using AD deployment, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160717.aspx.

How do it do this for .NET 4?  I tried unpacking the standalone .NET 4 installer and deploying the netfx_Extended_x86.msi package.  This didn't work.  After a reboot the event log shows that it tried but it failed to install with a message saying to run setup.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test it but look at this: [How to deploy .NET 4.0 Framework](http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-deploy-microsoft-net-framework-4.html)